# Problem building Pardiso in Julia on Windows

Tags: julia, pardiso

I am trying to use the Pardiso package in Julia together with the Pardiso library. However, I can’t build the package. When I look into the build log, I see this message:

Looking in “C:\Users\Rodrigo.julia\packages\Pardiso\yZsYO\deps” for libraries
found “C:\Users\Rodrigo.julia\packages\Pardiso\yZsYO\deps\libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll”, attempting to load it…
failed to load due to:
did not find libpardiso, assuming PARDISO 5/6 is not installed

I don't know if I need anything else besides the pardiso.lic and libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll files.
Thanks